# Append files into one file

Tags: vba, shell, excel, command-line

I'm a newbie in VBA and Shell using but I'm in need to use some.

I'm trying to append several files together :

Here is what I got so far :

```
Dim fso As Object
Dim oFile As Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\allFiles.py", True)

Shell "copy /b " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file1.py + " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file2.py + " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file3.py " & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\allFiles.py"
```

Comment: You want to copy all files contents and paste them in your `allFiles.py`?

Comment: Right, I want them all to be merged into one.

Comment: What's _bash_ got to do with this?

Comment: Do you really want to use a `Shell` statement and not vba statements?

Comment: No, I'm good for any solution, but It looked like the simplest solution when I looked around the internet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using VBA only, here is what you can do :

```
Sub GetOneFile()
    Dim fso As Object, oFile As Object, pathFileAllFiles As String 
    pathFileAllFiles = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\allFiles.py"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFile = fso.CreateTextFile(pathFileAllFiles, True)

    Dim pathsFiles(3) As String, i As Integer, textToWrite As String, pathFile As Variant
    pathFiles(0) = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file1.py"
    pathFiles(1) = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file2.py"
    pathFiles(2) = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file3.py"

    For Each pathFile As String In pathFiles
        textToWrite = GetFileText(pathFile)
        oFile.WriteLine textToWrite
    Next
    oFile.Close
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set oFile = Nothing    
End Sub

Function GetFileText(pathFile) as String
    Dim lineData As String, result As String
    Dim ff As Integer
    ff = FreeFile
    Open pathFile For Input As #ff
    Do Until EOF(ff)
        Line Input #ff, lineData
        result = result & VbCrlf & lineData
    Loop
    Close #ff
    GetFileText = result
End Function
```

Comment: Is it normal u never use `pathFile` in `GetFileText(pathFile)` ?
Also, shouldn't it end with `End Function`

Comment: Well, I tried for my tests : `textToWrite = GetFileText(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\file.py") oFile.writeLine textToWrite` and it doesnt seem to work.

Is `getFileText` returning anything ? If so can it be used as WriteLine parameter ?

Comment: K, I addedd `GetFileText = result` at the end of the function. But it looks like some line break aren't taken into account. \n is not interpreted as a line break, Using Chr(13) instead solved the issue

Comment: @Ellone Yes,I didn't remember that the `\n` doesn't mean anything in vba, I used the constant `VbCrlf` instead. Code updated to resolve bugs

Comment: Another unrelated question, do you know if I can do several replace using only one function. For example : `Replace(str, vbCrLf, "\n")
Replace(str, vbnewline, "\n")
Replace(str, vblf, "\n")` into only one replace, or using something to escape the character instead ?

Comment: Unrelated questions should be in another SO post.. However, there is no built in function to do several replace in one line. You could write your own, maybe using RegEx. I would be glad to help if you ask another SO Question